# Laravel Nova Images Field callback Function outside

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

in the nova resource I can define an image field with a media library addon package like:

```
Images::make('Main image', 'media_main')
    ->setFileName(static function($originalFilename, $extension) {
         return md5($originalFilename) . '.' . $extension;
}),
```

How can I use a function from the resource so that I can use the function multiple times for more Images fields and don't use duplicate code always for the same functionality.

For example:

```
public static function fileName($originalFilename, $extension) {
    return md5($originalFilename) . '.' . $extension;
}
```

So that in the fields section I can use multiple times:

```
Images::make('Main image', 'media_main')
    ->setFileName(self::fileName($originalFilename, $extension)),
```

The last call always results in an error message, because I can not grab the parameters. What I'm doing wrong? I think I have a misconception ...

Comment: Please always include the full error messages in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works. Is it the best solution?

```
->setFileName(fn($originalFilename, $extension) => self::fileName($originalFilename, $extension)),
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting, is because you are calling the function, not passing a `Closure`/`callable` as an argument.

`->setFileName(self::fileName($originalFilename, $extension))` is calling the static fileName function, not passing the function/Closure itself.

Here are a couple alternatives:

```php
class Resource extends \Laravel\Nova\Resource
{
    ...
    protected function filenameFormater()
    {
         return function ($originalFilename, $extension) {
              return md5($originalFilename) . '.' . $extension;
         };
    }
    ...
}

class SomeResource extends Resource
{
    ...

    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            ...
            Images::make('Main image', 'media_main')
                 ->setFileName($this->filenameFormatter()),
            ...
        ];
    }

}
```

Or:

```php
class SomeResource extends Resource
{
    ...

    public function fields()
    {
        $formatter = function ($originalFilename, $extension) {
            return md5($originalFilename) . '.' . $extension;
        };

        return [
            ...
            Images::make('Main image', 'media_main')
                 ->setFileName($formatter),
            ...
        ];
    }

}
```